# Javascript to hit a url and cause a open/save file dialog to appear (without a new window entirely)

Tags: javascript, download

What javascript could I use to open a url without leaving the current page and get an open/save file dialog to appear?

Comment: What URL are we talking about here? Any ol' URL? Some part of your own application?

Comment: Any URL, now just within my application.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think i get your question completely but if you are asking on how to use JS to invoke a open/save dialog for a file:

```
window.location = 'paste your url here';
```

The url should point to a resouce for which the browser is configured to show the open/save dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using...

```
Window.open("mylocation", "Download", "width=400,height=150")
```